# How to make ReSharper stop telling to remove if(myString == null)

Tags: resharper

I have seen some wired behaviour from the ReSharper and its suggestions. One that particularly made me buff was the one below. Now leave alone that a `string` can be null, and the suggestions is simply wrong. Can I change some settings to make it stop telling me to remove `if`-statements that are null checks?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's a R# suggestion? I don't get that warning with similar code. What do you see when you alt+enter on there? Are there any "inspection options" menu items?

Comment: I get the normal suggestions when a condition makes no sense `remove 'if' statement`, `replace expression with 'false'`, `use string.Equals` and a few more. Nothing special. About if it is from the resharper, I think it is, VS did not do that before I had it. On the other hand it has a light blub next to it. So I don't really know, but it would supprise me that if MS did this.